# adding column total and mean to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like below, I want the sum of col1 and the average of col2 and col3 in the last row.

```
col1   col2  col3
 1      3    1
 3      4    1
 3      5    2
 1      1    3
 2      2    4
 3      1    9
 2      3    5
 2      5    6

total 17.0    3.0   3.8
```

Please help.

Comment: Mind pasting the full dataframe, in proper format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

`.agg` function will aggregate the data and it can aggregate for sum, mean in one call.

`.loc` will add a new row with given index.

```
df.loc['new'] = df.agg({'col1':'sum', 'col2':'mean', 'col3':'mean'})
print (df)
     col1  col2   col3
0     1.0   3.0  1.000
1     3.0   4.0  1.000
2     3.0   5.0  2.000
3     1.0   1.0  3.000
4     2.0   2.0  4.000
5     3.0   1.0  9.000
6     2.0   3.0  5.000
7     2.0   5.0  6.000
new  17.0   3.0  3.875
```